# something wrong with thread assignment

Tags: java, networking

if I run  server and just one client, it is working fine.
But if I run one more client, then first client stops working.
and the thread handling request for first client,
suddenly, it handles request for second client.
so second client put a word in a chatting app, it is printed twice.
there is nothing I can do but to terminate it on Eclipse.(even stop button on the app is not working)
and server is working fine.
there is no Exception or something. there is no error log on the console View.
I can't even google this. because there is no message or log.
pls let me know what to do. where should I change the code.

```
public void connectServer() {
     try {
          
            socket = new Socket(ip, 8888);
            System.out.println("[Client]Server connected: "+ socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            outMsg = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            outMsg.println(id+"/"+"login"); 
     }catch (Exception e) {
          if(!socket.isClosed()) { stopClient();}
            return; 
        }
 receive();
} 

public void stopClient() {
     msgOut.append("Disconnected");
     
    try {
        inMsg.close();
        outMsg.close();
        if(socket!=null && !socket.isClosed()) {
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//stopClient

public void receive() {
    while(true) {
         try {
             String msg;
             String[] rmsg;
            inMsg = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while(true) {              
                    msg = inMsg.readLine();
                    rmsg = msg.split("/");                 
                    msgOut.append(rmsg[0] + ">"+rmsg[1] + "\n");          
                    msgOut.setCaretPosition(msgOut.getDocument().getLength());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             stopClient();
             break; 
        }
         
    }//while
}//receive


public void send(String send) {

   try {
       outMsg = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
       outMsg.println(id + "/" + send);
       
       msgInput.setText("");
   } catch (Exception e) {
     msgOut.append("Disconnected");
     stopClient();
        }
```

}

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Object obj = arg0.getSource();


    if(obj == exitButton) {
        System.exit(0);
    } 
    else if(obj == loginButton) {
        id = idInput.getText();

        label2.setText("name : " + id);
        clayout.show(tab, "logout");
        connectServer();
    } 
    else if(obj == logoutButton) {

        outMsg.println(id + "/" + "logout");
    
        msgOut.setText("");

        clayout.show(tab, "login");
        stopClient();
       
    } 
    else if(obj == msgInput) {
        String chat = msgInput.getText();
        send(chat);
       
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiChatClient mcc = new MultiChatClient("127.0.0.1");
    
}
```

}

```
public class MultiChatServer {
ExecutorService executorService;
private ServerSocket ss;
private Socket s;
ArrayList <Client> clients_connected = new ArrayList <Client>();


 void start() {
     executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool
             (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()); 
     
     try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
        System.out.println("sever start");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        if(!ss.isClosed()) {
            stopServer();
        }
        return;
    }
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("waiting");
                    s= ss.accept();
                    InetSocketAddress socketAddress = 
                            (InetSocketAddress) s.getRemoteSocketAddress();
                    System.out.println("Client("+socketAddress.getHostName()
                    +") connected ["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"]");  
                    Client client = new Client(s);
                    clients_connected.add(client); 
                    System.out.println("connected number: " +clients_connected.size());
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if(!ss.isClosed()) {
                        stopServer();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            
        }
    }   //run() 
};//runnable

    executorService.submit(runnable);
}//start()
    

void stopServer() {
    try {
        Iterator<Client>iterator=clients_connected.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Client client = iterator.next();
            client.socket.close(); 
            iterator.remove();
        }
        
        if(ss!=null && !ss.isClosed())
            
                ss.close(); 
            
        
        if(executorService!=null && !executorService.isShutdown()) 
            
            executorService.shutdown();
        
        System.out.println("서버멈춤");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    
}

class Client {
    Socket socket; 
    PrintWriter outMsg;
    public Client() {}
    public Client(Socket socket) { 
        this.socket = socket;
        
        receive();
    }
    
    void receive() {
        
    
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) { 
                        BufferedReader inMsg = new BufferedReader
                                (new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        String msg = inMsg.readLine();
                        System.out.println("handling: " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress()
                        +": " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        String[] rmsg = msg.split("/");
                        
                        if(rmsg[1].equals("logout")) {
                            sendAll("server/" + rmsg[0] + "is out.");
                            throw new IOException(); 
                            
                        }
                        
                        else if(rmsg[1].equals("login")) {
                            sendAll("server/"+rmsg[0]+"is entered.");
                        }
            
                        else {
                            sendAll(msg);
                        }
                        
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Disconnected: " +s.getRemoteSocketAddress()
                        +": " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        clients_connected.remove(Client.this);
                        s.close();
                    } catch (Exception e2) {}
                    
                    }
            
                    
            }
            
        };
        
        executorService.submit(runnable); 
    }
    
    void sendAll(String Data) {
        
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
            
                try {
                    outMsg = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
                
                    
                    for(Client client: clients_connected) {
                        client.outMsg.println(Data); //
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Disconnected: " +s.getRemoteSocketAddress()
                        +": " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        clients_connected.remove(Client.this);
                        s.close();
                    }catch (Exception e2) {}
                }
                    
            }
        };
        
        executorService.submit(runnable);
        
        
    }
}
    
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiChatServer server = new MultiChatServer();
    server.start();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpGwO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Both server and client are waiting to receive message from one another because of that both of them at waiting stage.

You can solve this by two way,

1. client send and server wait to receive or client wait to receive and server send.
2. Run send and receive on a separate thread